# Using VBA to Convert Integers into Text

Tags: excel, vba, range, comparison

I am trying to write a Vba that will take the numbers in one column and convert the numbers to text in another column.

For example:

4 will be “quarterly”, 
1 will be “annually” and 12 will be “monthly”.

This is what I wrote but only the last line is working.

```
Sub Convert ()

    Range("J6:J1447").Formula = "If(I6:I299=1, (""Annually""), """")"

    Range("J6:J1447").Formula = "=If(I6:I299=2, (""Semi-Annually""), """")"

    Range("J6:J1447").Formula = "=If(I6:I299=4, (""Quarterly""), """")"

    Range("J6:J1447").Formula = "=If(I6:I299=12, (""Monthly""), """")"

End Sub
```

Comment: Only the last line is "working " because each line overwrites the previous one.  Write a single formula that achieves your requirements and write that to the sheet once

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m posting this on my phone. I’ll try and clean it up a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("J6:J1447").formular1c1-"=if(rc[-1]=1,""ANNUALLY"",if(rc[-1]=2,""SEMI-ANNUALLY"",if(rc[-1]=4,""QUARTERLY"",if(rc[-1]=12,""MONTHLY"",""""))))"
```

You could also do an Last row option to not limit yourself with your range.

Comment: Here's another formula option: `Range("J6:J1447").FormulaR1C1 = "=CHOOSE(RC[-1],""Annually"",""Semi-annually"","""",""Quarterly"","""","""","""","""","""","""","""",""Monthly"")"`

Comment: Holy crap I feel like an idiot. Thank you, this worked.